# Add Controller outside of View

Tags: angularjs

I am using `RequireJS` alongside `AngularJS` and I want to give the body a controller.

The most important elements are `nav` and `.container`.

Now, `.container` changes automatically with the route, but I want to give the navigation a controller so I can change the current active tab. What I don't understand, however, is how to give `nav` a controller as this is a static element and isn't loaded alongside the route and is loaded before the async scripts (Angular, etc...) have loaded, so I can't use the ng-controller directive.

Answer (score 0):

One way to go about it would be to setup a separate controller at the top of the whole html, just below ng-app or beside it. That way you will have control over the static part of the application as well.

Something like:

```
<html ng-app="abc" ng-controller="appCtrl">
```

Then controller definition will be:

```
angular.module('abc').controller('appCtrl' .....)
```

Update: there was an error in the code module name was not matching.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the whole purpose of RequireJS? Is there no programmatic way to do this?

Comment: This is a common solution in Angular apps. I am working on an application using the same method. Yes, it might defeat the purpose, but if it's doing it while staying within the bounds of Angular then it's a good thing.

Comment: Okay, I tried this method but I got `[ng:btstrpd] `

Comment: It seems you might be loading AngularJS more than once, [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/btstrpd). Make sure you don't have more than one `ng-app` declarations

Answer (score 0):

If you're using UI-Router, you could create an abstract state under which exists your app. To clarify, your nav would still be part of your app, but your primary application would sit underneath an `ui-view` directive.

**Edit** you can read about abstract states [on the documentation page](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views). As a bonus, if you use controllerAs, your child controller will prototypical my inherit the properties of the parent. Keeps your application scope open, but nice and clean.